# Get the length of a TakeWhile?

Tags: rust

I want to use [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) on an iterator, and then count how many items are in the resulting iterator. Here is a simple toy program that demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3];
    let num_before_five = v.iter().take_while(|&&x| x != 5).len();
    println!("There are {} items before 5 occurs.", num_before_five);
}
```

[(Rust playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=baffdb36e19bd9d462107ca150176440)

When I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `len` found for type `std::iter::TakeWhile<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:3:47: 3:59]>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:61
  |
3 |     let num_before_five = v.iter().take_while(|&&x| x != 5).len();
  |                                                             ^^^ method not found in `std::iter::TakeWhile<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:3:47: 3:59]>`
```

The error suggests that a [`std::iter::TakeWhile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.TakeWhile.html) has no `.len()` method, which is true. While an arbitrary iterator might never terminate, since this one comes from a `Vec`, I know it is finite. I could get the length by counting it in a `for` loop, but it seems like there must be a more idiomatic way to do this in Rust.

How can I get the length of this `TakeWhile`?

Comment: One option is to [collect into a `Vec` and get the `len` of that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bfe150b66bce85c1aabbbb4f2866771). But this feels like it is inefficient, because I don't actually care about all the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3];
    let num_before_five = v.iter().take_while(|&&x| x != 5).count();
    println!("There are {} items before 5 occurs.", num_before_five);
}
```

Be aware, this is `O(n)`. OTOH, [`len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#method.len) is only available to `ExactSizeIterator`, which [`TakeWhile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.TakeWhile.html) is not.

Comment: Thank you! I figured this out just before I saw your answer. [Here's a playground link for the solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94a70c7d783f38ddc58e49d4ae87ade5). For my purposes, I want the items to be consumed, and there is no way for this operation to be faster than `O(n)` as the `take_while` condition must be evaluated once per element.